# Why place Composer in separate docker container?

Tags: php, deployment, docker

<sub>Note: this question is not strictly PHP-oriented, since both Docker and Composer can be easily used outside of the PHP ecosystem (although such cases would be rather rare IMO).</sub>

In one of the projects I work for, the production environment is set up in a way that uses an image with Composer only (i.e. https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/composer/) to get all the dependencies, and later copies them to actual PHP/FPM container (a so-called [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)). I couldn't figure any real sense in doing it vs simply `apk add`ing composer to the main container, running `composer install` on the main container, and then removing Composer from it during the build (note that this affects neither the image size nor layer count; the Composer binary could've been either added to the single `RUN` layer of all the other apps of the PHP/FPM source image or just `apk add`ed later during the build, and all the immediate files are removed eventually).

My current thoughts on separating Composer are:

PROS:

- if Composer breaks something, it doesn't propagate out of the container

CONS:

- the build process is slower due to the need to handle an additional image and container
- the build process gets more complicated due to the need to handle additional container and file copying
- the Composer is not run on the actual development machine, so all `ext-` checks ain't exectued and have to be forcibly disabled while installing dependencies, at the same time preventing you from verifying the completeness of the needed extensions
- it makes little logical sense by itself - Dockers are intended to separate services to make it easier to handle them; Composer is IMVHO not a service, but a part of the build pipeline itself.

Am I missing something?

---

<sub>BTW, this question is *not* about scenarios like https://medium.com/@othillo/adding-composer-to-php-docker-images-using-multi-stage-builds-2a10967ae6c1 (i.e. just adding the Composer binary from an image) or https://laravel-news.com/multi-stage-docker-builds-for-laravel (where multistage build could be arguably useful to handle Webpack, Node, JS, CSS etc.); some people that actually propose the solution with separate Composer image (https://chrisguitarguy.com/2017/12/16/multi-stage-docker-php/) provide no real rationale on the possible benefit vs the alternative solution, i.e. removing the Composer after installing dependencies.</sub>

Comment: Good question, I’ve not managed to find an answer yet myself.  Have you discovered anything since this post?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). It’s used to keep both the final image size and *numbers of layers* to a minimum. This results in less network traffic and a faster spin up time on machines where the image hasn’t been downloaded yet.

Comment: And allow you to don't install any sort of dev dependencies in images supposed to be deployed in production. The contrary is commonly seen as a vulnerability.

Comment: @Laiv you skip dev dependencies by `--no-dev`. I don't see how multi-stage helps with that any more.

Comment: @vaxquis, that depends on the language.  For many languages (C#, Go lang, C++), the dev environment can be hundreds of megabytes that are only needed for a short period of time.  The deployed software doesn't need any of that to run.  Without the compiler as part of the deployment, it also makes it harder to compile new malware if your container gets compromised (i.e. limit the blast radius).

Comment: @BerinLoritsch this question is specifically about Docker + Composer and, AFAIK, this directly implies PHP development (which was also extensively mentioned in the question). Also, I explicitly asked about scenarios *without* any other languages involved. As such, I don't see how "that depends on the language". If I weren't aware of the usefulness of multi-stage builds in other environments, I wouldn't mention all the links relevant to it.